# NIC works on Ubuntu, but not on Windows

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8, internet, network-adapter

I have a PC (with Windows 7) which its network adapter didn't work fine. The network adapter leds used to blink and Windows recognized the active connection, but it couldn't get a DHCP address from my router (the DHCP configuration its OK). I used a LiveUSB Ubuntu to test it, and it worked pretty fine, it got the new DHCP IP as supposed. 
After that, I supposed that a new Windows installation (and update) was required to make it work fine, so I installed Windows 8, I tested it with a static IP too, and

**--- NOW THE PROBLEM ---**

is the same as Windows 7: I can't access to the internet with Windows (even with a new installation).
PD: BIOS is restored with default values.

What happened in there? I searched on Internet possible problems/solutions and this is my last resource :(

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you installed drivers for your nic?

Comment: Yes, I have the proper drivers, I obviated that fact.

Comment: which WIFI card do you use?

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot into Ubuntu.
2. Access the information that'll tell you what the make and model of your NIC is. (I'd tell you how but I don't remember anymore, it's been a long time since I used Linux on a regular basis.)
3. Search the Internet for Windows drivers for that NIC.
4. Download them and save them somewhere that you can access from Windows.
5. Boot into windows.
6. Install those drivers.

Comment: Hi Mark and thanks for the fast response. I obviated the fact that the proper drivers have been installed and last updates have been installed too. I am thinking that, in any way, hardware have been modified in a very low level or something like that by any software, can this be possible?

Comment: Generally speaking no, software can't modify hardware. It could modify firmware, but that's all. In Windows you can run devmgmt.msc to pull up the Device Manager and see what devices Windows recognizes in your system, but if you don't see the NIC listed there then double-check that your NIC is really the model it says it is under Linux. I've seen Linux support NICs in the past by supporting something else that the NIC is compatible with. You might need to get more specific than that under Windows. Good luck!